# How do i preserve transparency in .fbx file?

Tags: materials, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have created a model, in it there is a transparent object. I made it transparent by changing both the alpha values as well as the Blend Mode. My problem now is that I can't retain transparency when exported to an .fbx file.
I have to re-change the Blend Mode each time after importing the .fbx.

Can anyone please help me to retain transparency settings, so that as soon as I import the file, I get a transparent object the same way it was before export?

[Here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QrLY29MKpsDScxsCrRw3cs82wt97ueIV/view)

I am using eevee.

if someone could help, i'll be really grateful.

Comment: FBX has not concept of Eevee's different transparency options, thus this information is not stored in the file. You would have to use a .blend file for this. Could you perhaps explain in what context you need to retain the blend mode, perhaps there's a different approach to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with the fbx export? You will need an alpha map texture to tell whatever is reading this what the alpha is. Chances are its going to just be a grayscale image at .3 , you could make an alpha map and then modify once its in the 3d package/ blender. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_mapping